# prepend first time, replace after the first time

Tags: javascript

I have html snippet below:

```
<div id="foo"><span id="bar"></span></div>
```

There's no whitespaces between tags above.
What can I do to meet my request:

1. use only one statement with javascript.
2. first time excuting the javascript statement, prepend a textnode(a string stored in a variable named `bazinga`) to the div#foo.
3. replace the textnode after first excution, I mean ,the 2nd, 3rd ... excution of the javascript statement.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: should the appended text node be placed before or after the span node?

Comment: Pure javascript or [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)?

Comment: I've voted to close this question as *too broad* - there are too many possible solutions. You also haven't provided any attempt to solve this problem yourself. We're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: @BillGregg It's not homework.I've tried several solution.One is add a textnode prepend to the div element in html template, so can I use `document.getElementById('#foo').childNodes[0].nodeValue` to replace that textnode everytime.But this solution seems so ugly(apologise, my English is poor).I need some graceful solutiion : )

Comment: if not homework, then why a single statement?

Comment: @Henrik single statement looks graceful to me...

Comment: it does not to me.. now functions on the other hand..

Answer (score 0):

plain old javascript, using a global variable for memory of previous action...
tested with chrome version something..

```
var firstReplace = true;
function replaceIntoElement(elmId){
    var div = document.getElementById(elmId);
    if(firstReplace){
        div.innerHTML = bazinga + div.innerHTML    
        return;
    }
    div.childNodes[0].nodeValue = bazinga;
}
```

that looks graceful.. even though using a global variable is bad, but then again, bazinga is also global... ;)

usage:

```
<button type="button" onclick="replaceIntoElement('foo')"> run me </button>
```